# Does "Time grows old" make sense?

Tags: meaning, expressions

If I say my love for my friend will never fade. Can I say

> My love will last till **time grows old**.

You know time is permanent, always there and never grows old. Does "Till time grows old." make sense?

Comment: until the end up of time?

Comment: It is a metaphor which can be easily understood IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a poetic usage meaning **forever**. Compare it to the start of the third verse of Robert Burns's poem ["A Red, Red Rose"](http://www.robertburns.org/works/444.shtml)

> Till a' the seas gang dry, my dear
>
> And the rocks melt wi' the sun

Along the same lines is the refrain from The Doors number ["Touch Me"](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/doors/touchme.html)

> Now, I'm gonna love you
>
> Till the heavens stop the rain
>
> I'm gonna love you
>
> Till the stars fall from the sky for you and I

There are lots of other examples from before Burns, after The Doors and all times in between, but these should give you the idea.